# saber cuantas veces aparece un dato en mi tabla

Tags: mysql, sql

tengo la siguiente tabla

```
id int (11)
ip varchar (255)
pais varchar (255)
```

cree un codigo con php que cada vez que alguien entra a mi web toma la ip de ese visitante la geolocaliza y la guarda en la tabla, ahora lo que me gustaria hacer es saber cuantas veces entraron desde los diferentes paises

probe esto:

```
$s = "select pais Count(pais) from contador group by pais";
$q = mysqli_query($cxn, $s);
while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($q)) {
  echo $r['pais']."<br>";
}
```

pero con esto solamente muestro los paises que hay en la tabla, lo que no logro hacer es que al aldo de cada pais me ponga la cantidad de veces que aparecen, ejemplo:

```
argentina (6)
brasil (2)
estados unidos (1)
```

alguna idea de como seguir?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu consulta parece correcta para el resultado que esperas, por lo que solo debería verse de este modo:

```
select pais, count(ip) as totalOrigen 
from contador 
group by pais;
```

**Modificaciones**

- Separa las columnas que deseas recuperar por `,`
- Dentro de la función `COUNT` pasa a la columna `ip` y no a país, pues es este valor el que nos interesa acumular y después con ayuda de `GROUP BY` separar por países cuantas ips le corresponden a cada una
- Dale un alias a la columna calculada
- Agrupa por la columna `pais`

Con lo anterior ya deberías obtener lo que deseas

Answer (score 1):

Según decís, necesitas contar la cantidad de veces que aparece cada país, o sea que hay que contar pais, y el agrupado es también por país. Tené en cuenta que la función de agregado `count()` va a funcionar en conjunto con la cláusula `group by`, o sea que le dice: **agrupame** los distintos países y además **contame** la cantidad de veces que aparece cada país, el código sería:

```
select pais, count(pais) as totalPorPais
from contador
group by pais;
```

Fijate que tu consulta solo difiere de esta en que le falta una coma `,` después de `select pais`. El alias `as` es opcional. Así que ahí debe estar tu error.

Si hicieras solo el `group by`, sin el `count()`, te va a devolver los distintos países, o sea: `select pais from contador group by pais`, y vos dirás para qué me sirve.. pero es útil cuando necesites una lista de todos los paises que tenes. También a mi me sirvió para comprender como funciona el agrupado